# Magento add db error \DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql Solution

Tags: error

> \DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql error magento

How to resolve this??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWmOO.png**How to resolve this?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue with MYSQL or php  version. i use version Msql "10.1.31-MariaDB" and PHP 7.0.28. version. 
Kindly ask your hosting provider to change version. hope it can solved.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187694/source-class-magento-framework-db-adapter-pdo-mysql-for-magento-framework-db). Hope it helps.

Comment: i have 1:10.3.13+maria~bionic

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
where is the problem? magento i 2.3.1 php 7.2

Comment: the command to install mariadb sudo apt install mariadb-server   ---> how to specifi version sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.1.31???

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mariadb-server-10.1.31
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mariadb-server-10.1.31'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mariadb-server-10.1.31'

Comment: I'm trying this https://www.tecmint.com/install-mariadb-in-debian/ but he continue to install maria db 10.3

Comment: Hi nacho, sorry i was out of town for health problem. you can directly ask to hosting provide to do that. or there could be an option in cpnel or whm. May i know which hosting company you use. Also did you check with sample data or not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue with sample data installation, please do fresh installation first after install sample data.

Run below command:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

After run setup upgrade command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```